# change an element's text with variable id

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, thymeleaf

I am designing a social network that has timeline and there is like button. I use AJAX to apply the like button on the server side. the problem is that I want to change the number of like for each post immediately after they have liked successfully. Because my elements are generated by for-each, I want to change the number of like for the exact element, I really have a problem with it.I am using thymeleaf.

I am looking for an idea that how to do this.

here is my html code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      <img th:if="${tweet.isFavorited()}" src="../static/images/like.png" th:src="@{/images/like.png}" th:class="like-img" th:id="${tweet.getId()}"  width="35" height="35"/>
      <img th:if="${!tweet.isFavorited()}"  src="../static/images/dislike.png" th:src="@{/images/dislike.png}" th:class="like-img"  th:id="${tweet.getId()}"   width="35" height="35"/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12" >
     <h6 th:if="${tweet.isRetweet()}" th:class="like-count" th:id="${tweet.getId()}"  th:text="${tweet.getRetweetedStatus().getFavoriteCount()}"></h6>
     <h6 th:if="${!tweet.isRetweet()}" th:class="like-count"  th:id="${tweet.getId()}"  th:text="${tweet.getFavoriteCount()}"></h6>
   </div>
</div>
```

and it is my script code:

```
$(function () {
  $(".like-img").click(function () {    
    event.preventDefault();

    var $post = $(this);
    var toSend = {
        "tweetId": this.getAttribute("id")
    }

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url : "like",
        data : JSON.stringify(toSend),
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        if(data.status == "success") {
            if ($($post).attr("src") == "/images/dislike.png") {
                $($post).attr('src','/images/like.png');
            }
            else {
                $($post).attr('src','/images/dislike.png');
            }

            return false;
        }
    });        
  });        
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so to make this work you will need to assign unique ids to the like-count elements, something like so:

```
<h6 th:if="${tweet.isRetweet()}" th:class="like-count" th:id="${tweet.getId()}_like_count"  th:text="${tweet.getRetweetedStatus().getFavoriteCount()}"></h6>
```

Then you can retrieve the current count, increment it, and set the text of the count element. Something like so:

```
var currentCount = parseInt($('#'+toSend.tweetId+'_like_count').innerHtml)
var newCount = currentCount++;
$('#'+toSend.tweetId+'_like_count').text(newCount);
```

Comment: actually $('#'+toSend.tweetId+'_like_count').innerHtml returns undifiend!

Comment: Use .text() instead of .innerHtml.
To set the text use 
     element.text('new text');